# Using Directive to Inject HTML with Directives and Data-Binding with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list that is populated with ng-repeat. I then have a directive that formats the content based on the content type field. I want to add directives on the injected HTML. How is this possible? Below is my code. The second statement in the if statement is not working (with ng-bind).

```
angular.module('mobileDashboardApp')
  .directive('detailFormat', function () {
    return {
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
          var entry = scope.entry;
          if(entry.type === 'action') {
              element.append('<button>' + entry.value + '</button>');
          } else if (entry.type === 'event') {
              element.append('<button ng-bind="entry.value"></button>');
          } else if(entry.type === 'comment') {
              element.append('<strong>Note:</strong> ' + entry.value);
          }

      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: The reason it's not working is you need to use `$compile` for angular to compile any directives you inject. Why do you only use `ng-bind` for one case and string concatenation for the others?

Comment: Also ... you seem to  trying to re-create a directive that already exists in core .... `ng-switch`

Comment: Your directive creates the appended DOM when the directive first links and does not change when `entry.type`  changes. Is that your intention? BTW it **is** possible to append  html that contain directives by using `$compile`. In fact anything the built-in directives do can be done in a custom directive.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using the markup in HTML for this?. Generally it is a terrible idea to manipulate the DOM yourself when using frameworks like Angular and Ember because they may trample all over your changes and get confused as to what has been rendered.

you can use some of the powerful template constructs to do this like ng-if.

```
<div ng-if="entry.type === 'action'">put something here<div>
<div ng-if="entry.type === 'event'">put something here<div>
<div ng-if="entry.type === 'comment'">put something here<div>
```

Hope this is helpful.